# Get device details using cordova-plugin-device in Ionic2

Tags: cordova-plugins, ionic2

I have tried following documentation here http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/device/ but am not getting anything back.

home.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Device} from 'ionic-native';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/home/home.html',
})
export class HomePage {
    public device;
    constructor() {
        this.device = {};
        platform.ready().then(() => {
            this.device['uuid'] = Device.device.uuid;
        });
    }
}
```

home.html

```
<li>Device UUID is {{device.uuid}}</li>
```

I have already ran `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-device`

UPDATE: i am testing the app using IonicView App.

Comment: Assuming you're executing this in a real device, what happens if you change the `console.log` by just `console.log(Device);`?

Comment: Yes, am testing on a real device (via Ionic View app).. I didn't mean to include the console.log as it will always show a warning on a browser and I am not sure how to check console.log whilst on a device.

Comment: Is that an Android device? If so, you can plug it in and use Chrome Inspector to find out what's going on there. If you want, I can write an answer with the information about how to do it.

Comment: Yes, Android device. I have worked out how to debug on a chrome browser. But need help on debugging on the app. I need to set setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled to true but where do I do this? In the config.xml? https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(boolean)

Comment: I have managed to debug with the device using `ionic run android` (i.e. app running on my android device). I can access and output the `device` object's properties (uuid, model, etc). It seems nothing was wrong with my initial code all along but issue seems to be when I access my app via the Ionic View, I get blank for all those properties. By the way, no need for the  platform.ready line.

Answer (score 0):

Debugging in the Chrome Debugger under different device sizes will not allow you to debug any type of code related to native device properties, hence you need to test your app through an emulator (ios/ android). Please note `ionic serve` allows you to view the app through the default browser application which isn't an emulator.

For reference on how to test your app through ionic on an emulator see the [CLI Docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/run.html)

Comment: Am loading the app on my android device directly using 'ionic run anroid'

Comment: Are you still having issues getting the properties?

Comment: Yes,  specifically when viewing the app in IonicView App.